# Is changing the name of the variable for my select statements necessary?

Tags: php, mysql

I've developed a habit of renaming my `SELECT` statement variable and I'm interested to know if it is necessary or not.

Here some typical code that I use:

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM tbl_one");

if(!$result_sql = $mysqli->query($sql))
{
// Error code here
}

while($a = $result_sql->fetch_assoc())
{
echo $a;
}

$sql2 = ("SELECT * FROM tbl_two");

if(!$result_sql2 = $mysqli->query($sql2))
{
// Error code here
}

while($b = $result_sql2->fetch_assoc())
{
echo $b;
}
```

For some reason I'm afraid there will be issues if I reuse the same `$sql` variable over again unless I rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good to have a different different variable for each statement you have as per coding standards even though PHP does not mind using same variable again and again.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a string, so you shouldn't care. Its fine to use the same variable again if you don't need the previous value anymore.

Comment: `$result_sql` is not a string in any way at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How does `$sql = ("SELECT * FROM tbl_one");` make `$sql` not a string?

Comment: How does `$sql` look like `$result_sql`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OP was talking about `$sql`.

Comment: So, what's the verdict on this discussion?

Comment: @Niko: Looks to me like all three variables are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically I opt not to reuse variable names for this sort of code, because of the risk of accidentally *not* overwriting one of them and getting strange results.

Then again, that problem doesn't go away just because you try to force yourself to remember to increment a number stuck on the end of the variable name.

Over time, as my code has improved, I've found that I very rarely need or want to execute multiple MySQL queries within a single PHP function, so the problem goes away entirely.

**tl;dr:** If I had a gun to my head, though... yes, *I'd probably do it the same way you did*. It's entirely subjective, though.

Comment: So then if you were writing the same code, you would do it in this same way?

Comment: @AndrewFox: I guess my point is that I _wouldn't_ write the same code! But, if I had a gun to my head... yes I believe I would.

Comment: wow...gun to your head? lol, guess I've still got a lot to improve on ;)

Comment: I know I didn't mention this in the question, but what about in an `AJAX` environment? I literally used `AJAX` for the first time three days ago, so I don't know if that's even relevant or not.

Comment: @AndrewFox Yeah I don't see the relevance. Or what an "AJAX environment" really is.

Comment: I marked @chandresh_cool answer as accepted because he was the first to reply. While you also offered a similar answer, yours ultimately leaves me with more questions, such as _"how should I write my code differently"_ and so on. It's nothing personal, I do appreciate your help.